# C i2c chip reading MCP9800 suddenly starts failing

Tags: c++, c, linux, filter, i2c

I have some code:

```
#define AMB_LSB 0.0625

void Ambient::read()
{
    uint32_t raw; 
    float filtered;

    uint8_t bytes = 2;
    uint8_t buf[bytes];

    if(i2c_smbus_read_i2c_block_data(i2c_bus_address, A_TEMP_REG, bytes, buf) < 0)
        printf("AMB Block Read Failed\n");

    uint32_t va = buf[0];
    uint32_t vb = buf[1];

    uint32_t result = ((va<<8)+vb);

    // 12-bit code
    raw = result >> 4; 

    filtered = filter.execfilter( raw );
    temperature = filtered * AMB_LSB;  << CALCULATION 

    printf("AMB buffers %d %d -> result %d -> raw %d -> filtered %d -> amb C %f\n",va, vb, result, raw, filtered, temperature);
}
```

It is code to read information from a MCP9800 via i2c. Sorry for including it but maybe it has something to do with it.

The function works well for about a dozen cycles until all of a sudden it starts having incorrect values. But with some strange variances.

**1.** If CALCULATION is the following

```
temperature = filtered * AMB_LSB;
```

I get this output:

```
temperature = ((float) filtered * (float) AMB_LSB);
```

WORKING

```
AMB buffers 28 240 -> result 7408 -> raw 463 -> filtered 463 -> amb C 28.937500 
AMB buffers 28 240 -> result 7408 -> raw 463 -> filtered 463 -> amb C 28.937500 
AMB buffers 28 240 -> result 7408 -> raw 463 -> filtered 1024 -> amb C 64.000000
```

FAILING

```
AMB buffers 29 0 -> result 7424 -> raw 464 -> filtered -**2147483648** -> amb C -134217728.000000 
AMB buffers 29 0 -> result 7424 -> raw 464 -> filtered **2147483647** -> amb C 134217728.000000
AMB buffers 29 0 -> result 7424 -> raw 464 -> filtered -**2147483648** -> amb C -134217728.000000
```

So once it starts failing, I can see the output of the filtered value is incorrect.

**2.** If CALCULATION is:

```
temperature = raw * AMB_LSB;
```

So that filtered is not used at all, the output is this:

WORKING

```
AMB buffers 29 48 -> result 7472 -> raw 467 -> filtered 0 -> amb C 29.187500 
AMB buffers 29 48 -> result 7472 -> raw 467 -> filtered 2147483647 -> amb C 29.187500
AMB buffers 29 64 -> result 7488 -> raw 468 -> filtered 468 -> amb C 29.250000
```

FAILING

```
AMB buffers **255 130** -> result **65410** -> raw **4088** -> filtered 2147483647 -> amb C 255.500000 
AMB buffers **255 130** -> result **65410** -> raw **4088** -> filtered -2147483648 -> amb C 255.500000 
AMB buffers **255 130** -> result **65410** -> raw **4088** -> filtered 2147483647 -> amb C 255.500000
```

See the asterixed numbers for output that is incorrect. For some reason when you don't use the filtered values the other numbers just start being incorrect too! All the way back to the bytes I pulled off the i2c chip.

So at first I see that maybe filtered is not working correctly. But to remove it also appears to make the raw unfiltered value incorrect as well. All execFilter() is doing is some averaging to prevent large random changes.

Also, I also made up a script via the CLI that used i2cget and it was very consistant in its returned values. There was no crashing or unexpected values.

Why would this be happening?

Comment: Note, instead of `((va<<8)+vb)`, use the `|` operator to combine bytes.  `((va<<8) | vb)` is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a hardware problem.  Many of your values are 0x7FFFFFFF, e.g. the SDA line is being controlled by the pullup resistor. This would happen if noise on the SDA line caused a spurious I2C stop condition -- the device would immediately tristate its output, and you would get nothing but high bits for the rest of the transfer.

RC lowpass filters are suggested on the SCL and SDA lines to slow down edges and block high frequency noise, helping to prevent such communication errors.

Comment: We've also made observations in my jobs environment that i2c communication is damageable for such reasons, especially for hardware that has HF processing on the same board.

Comment: If a HW problem like this happened, you would know from the error code.  I2C has per-byte acks from the slave.  So if the slave stopped responding, master would detect NACK condition and driver would return error.

Comment: @g-makulik: Right.  And a standalone test may not see the same errors, if the other circuitry creating the noise is not active.

Comment: @TJD: No.  I2C has per-byte acks from the recipient, which is the master during a read transfer.  Only the initial device address is ACKed by the slave, which is no help detecting a spurious STOP condition.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes it's dreaded to occur spuriously and being hard to debug! Especially if the i2c com is implemented in software (just toggling gpios).

Comment: I am using i2c_gpio_custom for my i2c channel. I am surprised this is happening since I tried on two different devices in different environments. But on one device I had another version of the software that doesn't seem to have these errors. It's a much older version that I can't debug, but it doesn't show these issues. I was somewhat worried that since this new version uses /sys/class/pwm and pthreads that maybe it would change the software stability, but I disabled them and it still just craps out after a few cycles. But none of my i2c comm functions are returning errors.

Comment: Could changes in my software cause louder noise on the i2c lines?

Comment: Actually this makes no sense. All those values (results from the chip) are not affected if I am using the filtered values. What is corrupting the variables? Not only are the result and raw variables not affected, but I have an ADC on the same bus and its results aren't looking any differently either.

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value from `i2c_smbus_read_i2c_block_data()` call, not just whether it is negative or not.

I bet it returns 0 or 1 when you get the failed transfers. Remember that the actual function depends on the adapter; I would never just assume it succeeds completely if it does not return an error, since it is documented to return the number of bytes instead.

Comment: Well you are correct about that. I put in a check and it consistently returns "2" even when the values are failing. Which is only confirming my suspicions that it's not a i2c_read at all, but some other error that is causing my variable to corrupt. I don't really need to handle anything more than errors (aka <0) since I the chip should always return two bytes from that address. If it returned 1 byte I am not sure what I  could do about it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being memory corruption from another class in my application.

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310496/i2c-smbus-filter-function-corrupting-variables)